# How to run mulitple keyframes on same page

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a game and I need some help with some html and css.
I have a page called "crime" and there it is 6 possible crimes you can take, on each of them I want to have a progress bar that counts down. I have made it work on the first one, but as I see on the code the keyframes doesnt go to a specific div, but everything that have the "fill" animation.
Since the crimes have different cooldown times I need to have them show another progress then the others.

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="in"></div>
</div>
```

```
.bar {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.in {
    animation: fill 20s linear 1;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}

@keyframes fill {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to post more code to make us understand precisely what you are doing.
From what you explained so far, I think you just need to create more keyframes and assigned them to the crime you want. 
So if you have this for every crime div

```
<div class="bar">
  <div class="in"></div>
</div>
```

then you could change the name of the inner div for each crime. E.g:

```
<div class="bar">
  <div class="in-1"></div>      //bar for crime 1
</div>

<div class="bar">
  <div class="in-2"></div>      //bar for crime 2
</div>

.in-1 {
  animation: fill1 20s linear 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.in-2 {
  animation: fill2 20s linear 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

@keyframes fill1 {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes fill2 {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

and so on for all the crimes.
Hope that helped :)

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for :D

Comment: glad I could help! :)

Comment: @SquatterSlayer but why re-creating the same animation? we can use the existing one with other elements

Comment: @TemaniAfif is right. We can (and should) use the same one. You need to create different keyframes only if you change something within them.